# Javascript Promise not waiting to resolve before next Then()

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, synchronization

Anyone know why this does not run synchronically? The last promise seems to resolve before the first

```
...

var promise = Promise.resolve();
promise.then( () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var file1 = fileChooserCSV.files[0];
        var reader1 = new FileReader();
        reader1.onload = function(){
            var csv = reader1.result;
            csvJson = csvJSON(csv);
            resolve();
        };
        reader1.readAsText(file1);
    });
});



promise.then( () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var file2 = fileChooserConfig.files[0];
        var reader2 = new FileReader();
        reader2.onload = function(){
            var config = reader2.result;
            configJson = JSON.parse(config);
            resolve();
        };
        reader2.readAsText(file2);
    });
});


promise.then( () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log('end');
        resolve();
    });
});
```

The reader onload methods never seem to execute though they really should (there is data passed to them), and did so before they were moved to the promise. As the onload doesn't run the resolve() never fires ether to go onto the next then(), but the last then() does execute...

This code runs in a chrome extension popup if that makes any difference?

Many thanks!

UPDATE..

Restructuring it in a classic nested way works fine

```
var file1 = fileChooserCSV.files[0];
    var reader1 = new FileReader();
    reader1.onload = function(){
        var csv = reader1.result;
        csvJson = csvJSON(csv);

        var file2 = fileChooserConfig.files[0];
        var reader2 = new FileReader();
        reader2.onload = function(){
            var config = reader2.result;
            configJson = JSON.parse(config);
            console.log('end');
        };
        reader2.readAsText(file2);
    };
    reader1.readAsText(file1);
```

Comment: You're not chaining promises properly for the promises to resolve in a specific order.

Comment: @zzzzBov thanks for your advice. In what way is it not chained properly would you say?

Answer (score 0):

did u tryied Promise.All().then... like that

```
var promise = Promise.resolve(3);
Promise.all([true, promise])
    .then(function(values) {
        console.log(values); // [true, 3]
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: Good idea! Actually it did eventually cross my mind to do it that way, and it makes more sense. But still doesn't quite explain why the original code doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

In JS runtime the 'then' are moved to another stack and are executed only when the call stack is empty.

For example, here you create I create a `Promise.resolve()` like you. But notice it's then is executed only after the entire code was executed. You will see on you screen '53' instead of expected '35':

```
const promise = Promise.resolve(3)

promise.then(res => {
  document.write(res)
})

document.write(5)
```

'then' is stored in additional stack and executed only later.

For more info take a look at [this perfect explanation](https://youtu.be/c35bj1AT3X8?t=1337) form Barak Chemo. Watch till 30:40.

Hope it helps